# Confused with the StripeDocs when it comes to integrating Apple Pay with Stripe in a native iOS application: StripeAPI.deviceSupportsApplePay()

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments, applepay

What am I missing? According to he [Stripe documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/apple-pay#native):

// Only offer Apple Pay if the customer can pay with it

but on viewDidLoad the code shown hides the button if (true) deviceSupportsApplePay.

```
applePayButton.isHidden = StripeAPI.deviceSupportsApplePay()
```

The problem I have is that according to the SDK:
deviceSupportsApplePay() Returns: YES if the device is currently able to make Apple Pay payments via one
/// of the supported networks. NO if the user does not have a saved card of a
/// supported type, or other restrictions prevent payment (such as parental controls).

Unless I'm missing something, the code should read:

```
applePayButton.isHidden = !StripeAPI.deviceSupportsApplePay()
```

If the device can use Apple Pay "DO NOT" hide the button. Is the documentation wrong or am I missing something?

[image]

[image]

Comment: This does look to be an error in the docs, based on the implementation of `canSubmitPaymentRequest`: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/blob/80ed9dd5dc025358c2afc896d2f781da6dc980c5/Stripe/StripeAPI.swift#L66-L87